# how to properly chain promises in protractor

Tags: angular, promise, protractor, deferred

Consider the following snippet:

```
        getApiEndpoints.billingCycle()
           .then(apiURL=>{
                return RestClient.doGet(apiURL);
            }).then(console.log(data))
```

In the above snippet, `getApiEndpoints.billingCycle()` and `RestClient.doGet(apiURL)` both return promises. The above code just hangs the web driver and later crash with timeout error.

Is there something I am missing here?

**UPDATE: RestClient.doGet(apiURL)**

```
function doGet(url){
var defer = Helper.getPromise().defer();
      request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
        if (response&&(response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201)) {
          defer.fulfill(JSON.parse(body));
        } else {
          defer.reject(error);
        }
        });
      return defer.promise;

}
```

**WHAT I TRIED**

```
let flow = browser.controlFlow();
           flow.execute(getApiEndpoints.billingCycle())
           .then((apiURL)=> console.log(apiURL))
```

gets me  `Failed: fn is not a function` error...

Comment: I don't know about Protractor, but the Promise chaining looks good to me.

Comment: What is `data` in the second then? I don't know if you can use it like that : /

Comment: @echonax data is the response apparently...

Comment: Can you try `then((data)=>{console.log(data)})` like the first one?

Comment: i did that: same thing... :/

Comment: Can you do a console.log in the first block? does apiURL print something?

Comment: yes it's a api url. In fact this all works if the last .then part is removed

Comment: Are you using the API call to get the URL and then you want the browser to load that particular URL through Protractor ?

Comment: No I am expecting a json from a REST call....See my update!

Comment: Can you provide more code.. where you are using json data in getApiEndpoints.billingCycle()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protractor has its own [control flow of Promises](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) and non -Webdriver promises are not chained by default

So there are two ways you can handle this.I personally prefer the second one as it leverages the options provided by Protractor config.

1. Insert a non-Web-driver promise into Protractor Control flow.There is a [beautiful post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/17/asynchronous-testing-protractor-angular/) on how to implement this.
2. If this is something related to data setup or a pre-requisite for execution I would suggest adding it in `onPrepare()` section of [conf.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L420)

> - You can specify a file containing code to run by setting onPrepare to    * the filename string. onPrepare can optionally return a
>     promise, which    * Protractor will wait for before continuing
>     execution. This can be used if    * the preparation involves any
>     asynchronous calls, e.g. interacting with    * the browser. Otherwise
>     Protractor cannot guarantee order of execution    * and may start the
>     tests before preparation finishes.

```
 onPrepare: function() {
       return getApiEndpoints.billingCycle()
           .then(apiURL=>{
           return RestClient.doGet(apiURL)
   }).then(
       // Any value you want to set with API response. Some examples below
       browser.profile = data.user.name;  
       browser.params.password = data.user.password;    

       // Or else get the complete JSON onto global browser and use it through-out test case
       browser.apiresponse = data;

       )
    },
```

Comment: Can you provide some stack trace ..  is it being thrown at the step `flow.execute()` .. c

Comment: Should'nt this say `.then(function(data) {` or `.then(data => {`?

Answer (score 2):

> Failed: fn is not a function

You should pass a *function* to `execute()` (do not call it):

```
flow.execute(getApiEndpoints.billingCycle)
```

Or, if needed to pass parameters:

```
flow.execute(function () {
    return getApiEndpoints.billingCycle(param1, param2);
});
```

Comment: @beNerd you can wrap it into a function (updated the answer), hope that helps.

Comment: you forgot to put return there :) It works fine....basically I should have returned a closure...thanks a ton for your help!